# What's the derivative of this quadratic with respect to matrix A?

Tags: matrix-calculus

What's $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\left((x_1-(\mathbf{I}_T\otimes \mathbf{A})x_2)^\intercal \mathbf{K}^{-1}(x_1-(\mathbf{I}_T\otimes \mathbf{A})x_2)\right)$$?

K is symmetric

I'm thinking we could use some sort of chain rule getting $$2(x_1-(\mathbf{I}_T\otimes \mathbf{A})x_2)^\intercal \mathbf{K}^{-1}(-x_2)$$

Am I correct?

Comment: What does $\otimes$ stand for here?

Comment: @amd stands for the kronecker product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typing convenience define
$$\eqalign{
 y &= (I_n\otimes A)x_2-x_1\,\,\,\,\,&\big(I_n\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n},\,A\in{\mathbb R}^{p\times q}\big) \cr
 M &= K^{-1} = M^T &\big(M\in{\mathbb R}^{pn\times pn}\big) \cr
}$$
Write the cost function in terms of these new variables and find its differential.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= y^TMy \cr&= M:yy^T \cr
d\phi &= 2M:dy\,y^T = 2My:dy = (2Myx_2^T):(I_n\otimes dA) \cr
  &= B:(I_n\otimes dA) = {\rm vec}(B):{\rm vec}(I_n\otimes dA) \cr  
}$$
where $B\in{\mathbb R}^{pn\times qn}$

Now the trick is vectorizing the Kronecker product on the RHS.
$$\eqalign{
E_k &= I_q\otimes e_k^T &\big(E_k\in{\mathbb R}^{q\times qn}\big) \cr
U &= \big[\,E_1\,\,\,E_2\,\,\ldots\,\,E_n\,\big]^T &\big(U\in{\mathbb R}^{qn^2\times q}\big)\cr
{\rm vec}(I_n\otimes dA)
 &= (U\otimes I_p)\,\,{\rm vec}(dA) = &(U\otimes I_p)\,\,da \cr
}$$ where the {$e_k$} vectors are the columns of $I_n$ matrix.

Substituting
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= b:(U\otimes I_p)\,da   &= (U^T\otimes I_p)\,b:da \cr
  &= {\rm vec}(I_p{\hat B}U):da &= {\hat B}U:dA \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A} &= {\hat B}U \cr
}$$
where ${\hat B}\in{\mathbb R}^{p\times qn^2}$

Since they have *different shapes*, $\,{\hat B}\ne{B},$  however since they have the *same elements* and relative ordering $\,{\rm vec}({\hat B})={\rm vec}({B})=b.$

---

**Update**

Here is a more direct way of writing this result in terms of the problem variables
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A}
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n\;\left(e_k^T\otimes I_p\right)B\,\big(e_k\otimes I_q\big) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n\;2\left(e_k^T\otimes I_p\right)Myx_2^T\,\big(e_k\otimes I_q\big) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n\;2\left(e_k^T\otimes I_p\right)K^{-1}\big((I_n\otimes A)x_2-x_1\big)x_2^T\,\big(e_k\otimes I_q\big) \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks Greg. ;)

Comment: If you want, I asked another question. This time it's about the notation that's used. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991410/a-doubt-on-the-general-rule-to-derive-scalar-functions-w-r-t-matrices

Comment: I've been redoing this (to learn), and I have a doubt. Wouldn't $\phi=Tr(y^\intercal M y)$ imply that $\phi=Tr( M yy^\intercal)$? If so, I think your $M$ is not being transposed when it should, no?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. But in this problem, the matrices $(M,K)$ were specified as symmetric.

Comment: of course. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks ;)