# How to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{Q}}\left(x_2^\intercal (\mathbf{I}_T\otimes \mathbf{Q})^{-1}x_2\right)$?

Tags: matrix-calculus

How to find $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{Q}}\left(x_2^\intercal (\mathbf{I}_T\otimes \mathbf{Q})^{-1}x_2\right)$$?

Q is symmetric

I'm thinking we could use some sort of chain rule getting $$ x_2 x_2^\intercal \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{Q}}(\mathbf{I}_T\otimes \mathbf{Q}^{-1})$$

However, being the derivative of a scalar function w.r.t a matrix, I would expect it to have the same dimensions as Q, but I'm not getting them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $(I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q)^{-1} = I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1}$ so we have
\begin{equation}
 x_2^T (I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1}) x_1
\end{equation}
The matrix $I_T \otimes Q^{-1}$ looks like this 
\begin{equation}
 I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
Q^{-1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & Q^{-1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & Q^{-1} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & Q^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
This means that if we partition the vectors $x_1,x_2$ into subvectors of same dimensions as $Q$, i.e. as follows
\begin{equation}
 x_{1,2} = \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{1,2}^{1}\\
  x_{1,2}^{2}\\
  \vdots \\
  x_{1,2}^{\textbf{T}}
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $x_k^{t}$ is a vector of length equal to the number of rows/columns of $Q$.
We get that 
\begin{equation}
 x_2^T (I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1}) x_1
 =
 (x_2^{1})^T Q^{-1} x_1^1 + (x_2^{2})^T Q^{-1} x_1^2 + \ldots + (x_2^{\textbf{T}})^T Q^{-1} x_1^{\textbf{T}}
\end{equation}
or simply
\begin{equation}
 x_2^T (I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1}) x_1
 =
 \sum_{t=1}^{\textbf{T}}
 (x_2^{t})^T Q^{-1} x_1^t
 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
We know that in general
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial X}
 a^T X^{-1} b
 =
 -X^{-T}ab^T X^{-T}
\end{equation}
When $X$ is symmetric, we get
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial X}
 a^T X^{-1} b
 =
 -X^{-1}ab^T X^{-1}
 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Applying this to what we have in equation (1)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial Q}
 x_2^T (I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1}) x_1
 =
 \frac{\partial}{\partial Q}
 \sum_{t=1}^{\textbf{T}}
 (x_2^{t})^T Q^{-1} x_1^t
 =
 \sum_{t=1}^{\textbf{T}}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial Q}
 (x_2^{t})^T Q^{-1} x_1^t
\end{equation}
Using equation (2), we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial Q}
 x_2^T (I_{\textbf{T}} \otimes Q^{-1}) x_1
 =
 -
 \sum_{t=1}^{\textbf{T}}
 Q^{-1}x_2^{t}(x_1^t)^T Q^{-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: Ahmad, thanks for the answer. I have to sleep now, but tomorrow I'll read this. May I interest in this somewhat similar question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989119/whats-the-derivative-of-this-quadratic-with-respect-to-matrix-a

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. welcome, if you found this useful, please make sure to upvote as it helps other readers on this site :). I will check the other question as soon as i can, gotta head to work :)

Comment: Ahmad, thanks ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\M{{\rm Mat}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\L{\left(}\def\R{\right)}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
ease of typing, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
I &= I_T \qquad x = x_1 \qquad y = x_2 \\
X &= \M(x) \implies x = \v(X) \\
Y &= \M(y) \implies y = \v(Y) \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}\L A^TB\R$$
Use this to rewrite the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= y^T(I\otimes Q)^{-1}x \\
 &= y^T\L I\otimes Q^{-1/2}\R \L I\otimes Q^{-1/2}\R x \\
 &= \v\L Q^{-1/2}Y\R^T \v\L Q^{-1/2}X\R \\
 &= Q^{-1/2}Y:Q^{-1/2}X \\
 &= YX^T:Q^{-1} \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= -YX^T:Q^{-1}dQ\,Q^{-1} \\
 &= -Q^{-1}YX^TQ^{-1}:dQ \\
\p{\phi}{Q} &= -Q^{-1}YX^TQ^{-1} \\
}$$

Comment: So you are saying, to find the derivative, all we need to do is: Find the differential, and transpose the result?